# Can I use the internal Atmega32u4 clock for USB applications?

Tags: atmega32u4

I believe I can set a fuse in the atmega32u4 to tell it to use its internal clock rather than an external crystal.

Would the internal clock be acceptable for using the microcontroller as a USB HID device?

Answer (score 1):

Had you checked the data sheet before posting a question, you would see the first page bullet point:

> Crystal-less operation for Low Speed mode

and later detail:

> 21.4 Crystal-less Operation
>   To reduce external components count and BOM cost, the USB module can be configured to operate in lowspeed mode with internal RC oscillator as input source clock for the PLL. The internal RC oscillator is factory
>   calibrated to satisfy the USB low speed frequency accuracy within the 0°C and +40°C temperature range.
>   For USB full-speed operation only external crystal oscillator or external source clock can be used.

Since HID devices are typically low-speed, for your requirement you can probably do this and implement a low speed device.

If you want to operate at full speed you need a crystal.  The PLL permits using either an 8 or 16 MHz crystal to operate the MCU and develop the internal clock required for USB.

Note additionally that if you use the internal clock it is unclear if you will be able to program the chip over USB - so be sure to provide a way to access the ISP signals.

Comment: Thanks. I always try to look for the information in the datasheet but I find it difficult most of the time to find what I'm looking for. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

> Would the internal clock be acceptable for using the microcontroller
>   as a USB HID device?

I don't think so. The device datasheet states that the

> Internal RC oscillator ... At 3V and 25C, this calibration gives a
>   frequency of 8MHz ±1%.

1% means 10,000 ppm, while USB in FS mode requires clock calibrated to 2,000 ppm. Which is 5X outside specified value. I saw USB devices that can tolerate 4,000 ppm, but 10,000 ppm will definitely kill any real data packets. The device might enumerate (becuse the control transactions use relatively short packets, but any 64-byte packets will fail for sure.

More, usually USB needs either 6, 12, or 24 MHz to get proper internal frequencies, while it is not immediately clear if these frequencies can be generated internally from 8-MHz base clock.

However, Low-speed USB devices need only 1.5% frequency tolerance, so it might be ok if you can hook this clock to internal USB hardware.

Comment: This device datasheet claims the internal PLL is sufficient for USB applications, but to your point the datasheet states the PLL requires an external clock or crystal input. To answer OP , the USB PLL must be fed from external clock or crystal  according to datasheet